# How to retrieve files metadata of files stored in a storage account on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I need to retrieve the name of files stored in a storage account on azure. I don't have experience about azure and how to work with files i was trying to get them using KQL but it didn't work with me...

Comment: I don't think KQL will help. What you need to do is use one of the available Storage SDKs and perform listing operations on blob container or file share.

Comment: `I don't have experience about azure and how to work with files` - I would highly recommend that you learn about Azure Storage first. That would make things much easier for you.

Comment: @GauravMantri what about logic apps do you think it can help me ?

Comment: Logic apps can certainly help you however you really need to understand Azure Storage first so that you know what information you want to fetch and how you can fetch it. After that, there are multiple ways to get that information (Logic apps being one of them).

Comment: Please refer this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file-metadata

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to retrieve metadata of files stored in a storage account on Azure :

**You can use azure cli to retrieve metadata of files stored in a storage account on Azure.**

Use below command to get the files metadata :

```
az storage file metadata show --account-name "StorageAccountName" --account-key "StorageAccountAccessKey" --path "path-to-your-file" --share-name "FileShareName"
```

For more information, refer [az storage file metadata | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file/metadata?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_file_metadata_show)

**You can use storage REST API to retrieve names and properties of the files stored in Azure Storage Account.**

For more information, refer to this document :  [Get File Metadata (FileREST API) - Azure Files | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file-metadata)

**You can use Logic App to retrieve metadata of the files stored in Azure Storage Account.**

In the actions in the Logic App Designer, you can use **Get File Metadata** action to get the metadata of the file stored in Azure Blob and File Storage.